# Quicker Syntax for Assignment of Dot-Notation Methods Return Values to Original Variable

Tags: c#, list, linq, ienumerable

I often write LINQ expressions where I want to capture the return value in the original variable that the method was executed upon. Not all LINQ methods modify the original object but return a new object with modified values based upon the original object.

For example, I often find myself writing statements such as

```
selectedItems = selectedItems.Select( x=> x.Prop == value);
```

This has an ever-so-slight code-smell to me. It reminds me of performing operations:

```
value = value + 1;
```

versus

```
value+=1;
```

Is there any quick syntax for performing this assignment?

Comment: I see no code smell there. Looks perfectly normal to me.

Comment: On the other hand, I don't find myself writing those very often at all. Have you got some concrete examples of when you do this?

Comment: ```selectedItems.Where( x=> x.Prop == value);``` is this what you want ?

Comment: The answer is very simple: no.

Comment: Your example won't compile (unless it is unusual): `selectedItems` is `IEnumerable<T>` but the result of the `Select` is `IEnumerable<bool>` and `T` is not `bool` (since `bool` has no property `Prop`) so it is a type mismatch error.

Comment: A single refinement seems fine, if you are doing multiple refinements in a row (e.g. filtering gated by user selections), then perhaps you need to reconsider how you do that (e.g. using a loop and a data structure describing filters) instead.